# Construct A String Using StringBuilder from a List using elements index

Tags: java

I am a java beginner and want to build a string from elements in a list using its elements index, the code runs fine yet i want to learn if there are other ways to improve upon it.Below is my sample code and I'm welcomed to suggestions.

```
String buildObject(List<Integer> obj){
    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i ++){
       int m = obj.size() - 1;//will be nine
       if(i == 0 && i < 2){
           name.append(obj.get(0))
                   .append(" & ")
                   .append(obj.get(1));
       }else if (i >= 2 && i != m) {
           name.append(", ");//between second and before last value
            name.append(obj.get(i));
       }else if(i == m){//last value
           name.append(" and ")
                   .append(obj.get(m));
       }

   }
  return name.toString();
   }
```

Comment: (Welcome to CodeReview!) (The indentation of your code is slightly inconsistent - do you use an [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)? `buildObject()` lacks the closing `}`.) Title and body of your question use `array`, the parameter to `buildObject()` is (`java.util.`?)`List<Integer>`. Please execute your code for, say, five items and present the output.

Comment: is there any reason why you use `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @greybeard edited code to include your suggestions, as I am not by a pc right now. I will include sample results latter. Thank you

Comment: Please heed the guide linked in [Simon Forsberg's comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189723/construct-a-string-using-stringbuilder-from-a-list-using-elements-index?noredirect=1#comment362917_189723): you are welcome to post new/significantly modified code - as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your code is concerned, it would be more efficient to apply the strings from the first 2 and the last elements outside the loop.  This will eliminate 3 elements from the loop:

```
String buildObject(List<Integer> obj){
   StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
   name.append(obj.get(0))
       .append(" & ")
       .append(obj.get(1));
   int limit = obj.size() - 1;
   for(int i = 2; i < limit; i++){
       name.append(", ");
           .append(obj.get(i));
   }
   name.append(" and ")
       .append(obj.get(limit));
   return name.toString();
}
```

Comment: Exactly how I would write it. Might give a wrong(?) result if the input is smaller than 3 elements though. Then again, you're only outputting a different result from the OP if there's exactly 2 input elements.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Streams` and `MessageFormat` and skip the StringBuilder...

```
List<T> list;

//not mentioned in your question, so...
assert list != null && list.size() > 1

if (list.size() > 2){
    int limit = list.size()-1;        
    return new MessageFormat("{0} and {1}" , list.stream().limit(limit).collect(Collectors.joining(" & "), list.get(limit)).toString();
}else{
    return new MessageFormat("{0} & {1}",list.get(0), list.get(1)).toString();
}
```

Comment: Apart from featuring an `else` where "the `if return`s", this doesn't compile. Once it does: does it reproduce the output?

Comment: @greybeard thank you for pointing out the compile errors. i think even though it is not the best answer, i just leave it be... maybe it can be used as a 'bad example of an answer' - if you disagree let me know and if it's reasonable i'll delete this answer. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Been there, done that (leave something in as an example of what isn't advisable, for readers to form their own opinion, see votes&comments) - guess I agree.

Comment: @greybeard thanks for your reply, i hope my next contributions will be of higher quality...